# Event is not firing up after the 2-3 hour long import process

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, event-observer, import, dataflow

I again ran into a weird issue. I have registered an observer for an event that is firing up when the Advance data flow profile finishes its execution completely.
I have checked this successfully when i only import 10-20 products at a time but when i comes in real situation importing 5K to 6K products the observer is not calling up at all after finishing the execution.

What I suspect: I am thinking that after this long hour of application run the object is alive in memory :-p just guessing.

I have set the admin session to some higher and checked the admin is not logging out.

Comment: It takes 3hrs to import 6k products? Apart from the fact that sounds fundamentally broken, have you never heard of Magmi or uRapidflow

Comment: @sonassi Yes i have heard about Magmi. Is it support event system i need to fire when import completes.

Comment: You can also use this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-products-categories-multiple-images-and-custom-options.html

Comment: @ravisoni: Which event did you register? Do you want to solve the problem or recommendations for other import methods? Would be great if you can clarify the question

Comment: @Alex Hi. thanks for your comment but i figured out the problem and its working fine.

Comment: @ravisoni: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it (unfortunately you have to wait a while until you can accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution i added the `Mage::dispatchEvent()` at the end of the script with my custom event and it worked fine.

Thanks all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this product import/export extension

[Extension: https://marketplace.magento.com/commerceextensions-ext2965.html](https://marketplace.magento.com/commerceextensions-ext2965.html)

Though its a paid extension but its worth every money, it uses dataflow profile and you can extend this extension for your need.